# Fastest way to update a few million JSON values in postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql, database-performance

I have a Postgres table `User`. User has many attributes, including `settings`, a JSON (JSONB) dictionary.

I have a CSV file with a few million user IDs, every one of which needs to update the dictionary with the following query:

```
        UPDATE "User"
        SET preferences = jsonb_set(
            jsonb_set(
                preferences,
                '{setting1}',
                'true'::jsonb,
                true
            ),
            '{setting2}',
            'true'::jsonb,
            true
        )
        WHERE id = '{my-user-id}';"
```

This basically just updates 2 fields within the dictionary in a single query.

My problem is that in testing, running this sequentially with a python script yielded only a few hundred updates per second, which would take many hours to complete.

How can I speed this up?

Comment: don't use json, a normalized table would be faster than creating a new json for all rows

Comment: We have to stick with JSON for the time-being :)

Comment: Because of choosing json, it’s now slow by design. Not much you can do about that. Maybe creating a fresh table with the correct content might be faster, and when do rename the tables

Comment: Given that you're stuck with JSONB and assuming that there is an index on `id`, the next area to tackle will be changing the query from row-by-row to a set operation. Instead of calling the query for each change, pass a collection of `id`s and settings. If `setting1` and `setting2` are the same for all updates, then passing the scaler settings and an array of `id`s would be even easier.

Comment: Are you running every update in a separate transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have it, but asking just for case - the `Update` in a loop requires an *index* on the column `ID` - without it a *seqScan in a loop* is open which leads to a catastrofic performance.

Anyway far better approach (as commented) is to use a single update.

I'd recomend the create a helper table containg all `ID`'s that should be updated (I call it `upd`) and than use a single `update`as follows

```
    UPDATE test
    SET preferences = jsonb_set(
        jsonb_set(
            preferences,
            '{setting1}',
            'true'::jsonb,
            true
        ),
        '{setting2}',
        'true'::jsonb,
        true
    )
    WHERE id in (select id from upd);
```

This will trigger a *hash join* that makes the update efficient - my test show an update of 1M row in 6+ sec.

**Test**

```
create table test as
with dt as (
select id, 'x' x, 'y' y, 'z' z 
from generate_series(1,1000000) t(id)
)
select id, to_jsonb(row(id, x, y, z)) preferences from dt;
 
create table upd as
select  id id
from generate_series(1,1000000) t(id);
```

*Query Plan*

```
Update on test  (cost=18534.19..59754.97 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=6113.324..6113.329 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=3034860 read=11699 dirtied=27083 written=15385, temp read=22408 written=25430
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=18534.19..59754.97 rows=721614 width=44) (actual time=1240.077..4040.943 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (test.id = upd.id)
        Buffers: shared hit=4096 read=11693 dirtied=11693, temp read=22408 written=25430
        ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..25796.28 rows=1443228 width=42) (actual time=0.048..200.050 rows=1000000 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2048 read=9316 dirtied=9316
        ->  Hash  (cost=18531.69..18531.69 rows=200 width=10) (actual time=1239.799..1239.801 rows=1000000 loops=1)
              Buckets: 131072 (originally 1024)  Batches: 16 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3716kB
              Buffers: shared hit=2048 read=2377 dirtied=2377, temp read=7442 written=14119
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=18529.69..18531.69 rows=200 width=10) (actual time=432.261..1051.496 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                    Group Key: upd.id
                    Batches: 101  Memory Usage: 5481kB  Disk Usage: 32064kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=2048 read=2377 dirtied=2377, temp read=7442 written=10464
                    ->  Seq Scan on upd  (cost=0.00..15708.75 rows=1128375 width=10) (actual time=0.018..147.495 rows=1000000 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=2048 read=2377 dirtied=2377
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=10
Planning Time: 0.146 ms
Execution Time: 6120.546 ms
```

Comment: Thank you for the detail. This was the approach I went with, although it took several hours instead of a few seconds. I suspect this is because I used individual transactions for each update (+ my DB is much larger).

Accepting this answer.